# Unable to join game using WiFi connection?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, android, networking, wifi

My brothers and I have three devices running Android; a Motorola XT980, an Alcatel Touch and a tablet, connected via WiFi.

We all run Minecraft PE v0.8.0 and have no problems joining games with any of the devices.

However, when we host a game using the Motorola XT980, the other two devices are unable to join the game.

What could be causing this problem and how do we resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Is the install on this device set to allow local multiplayer? Even if it's off it will still be able to join other games, just will not be able to host them (in my experience)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check your router settings or whatever device establishes the ad-hoc hotspot. Some offer settings allowing you to forbid communication between WiFi defices (so only outbound traffic is allowed).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the multiplayer settings of Minecraft on the XT980 set up the same as the other devices you have no problems connecting to, it may be the WiFi settings of the XT980 so check that menu. When connecting to the XT980, are you all connecting to a different router? If so, check the WiFi settings on that too. Does the XT980 have any anti-virus apps installed that offer firewall features? If so, this app may have put restrictions on WiFi access.